# best way to pass multiple variables to diiferent pages without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi in my mobile application I want to create multiple variables and want to access them in different html files, without using ajax. What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it  good old fashion ways

1. Use cookies
2. use query string paramaters in the URL

Comment: @Daveo Thanks for response. Will it support in blackberry5?

Comment: @PramodD yes, this has been around for years.

Comment: I also just found this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage  it says it supports     Android,  BlackBerry(OS 6.0 and higher), iPhone

Comment: @Daveo Thanks for link, Actually I also want to support for blackberry5. So I will go with cookies.